# bash process substitution with brace

Tags: bash, process, substitution

whenever I used awk in bash shell scripts, I usually do like this:

```
cat XXX | awk -f <(cat - <<'EOF'
    # awk script here
EOF
                  )
```

However, If the heredoc contains something like `{2,}` then the braces disappear. This only happens when bash process substitution `<(...)` is used.  I suspect that it may be part of brace substitution.  For example:

```
cat <(cat - <<'EOF'
{3,}
EOF
)
```

prints

```
3
```

If I escape with backslash, it prints as it is.  For example:

```
cat <(cat - <<'EOF'
\{3,\}
EOF
)
```

prints

```
\{3,\}
```

Can you tell me the reason of this, and how I can get `{3,}` in the output?

Thank you.

Comment: I am getting `{3,}` in output [same as in this demo](http://ideone.com/n3DPfm)

Comment: This happens on bash 3.2.57 on Mac. bash-4.1.2 on Linux does not have this problem.

Comment: Why are you using `cat` twice? Why not `cat <<'EOF'
{3,}
EOF`? (with newlines)

Comment: @anubhava the first cat is just for the example, I use awk instead of the first one

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason why you enter you scripts like this.  That seems a useless use of -f cat and here document. You can enter multi-line in place scripts easily with `\` line continuation

```
$ seq 10 | awk '/10/{print "double digit"} \
                 /8/{print "2 cube"} \
                 END{print done}'
2 cube
double digit
```